# Find Mode in Postgres SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like this -

`cdr_pkey as serial, calldate as timestamp, src as text, duration as bigint`

I need to find top 10 most frequent numbers in 'src' column, together with the number of occurrence in the table by using SQL query.

I tried by exporting to Excel and run Mode function but the records are around 7 million so it is not so efficient.

PS. I'm using PostreSQL 9.1

Comment: Does that help? http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Aggregate_Mode

Comment: @chl Thanks but not really. I prefer to have a step by step explanation so I can learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select 
    src as text,
    count(*) as total
from t
group by 1
order by total desc
limit 10;
```